# Unsupported value "ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol": OpenSSL not available at build time

Tags: node.js, docker, apache-kafka

I am using Node.js 14, but the 'security.protocol' configuration is not available at build time when the application is attempting to connect with the Kafka broker. We have tried various solutions, including using openssl-dev in the Dockerfile, but the issue persist

```
/data/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:54

 this._client = new SubClientType(globalConf, topicConf);
             

Error: Unsupported value "ssl" for configuration property "security.protocol": OpenSSL not available at build time
    at Producer.Client (/data/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:54:18)
    at new Producer (/data/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/producer.js:75:10)
    at /data/node_modules/good/lib/monitor.js:137:32
    at Object.internals.forOwn (/data/node_modules/good/lib/monitor.js:232:9)
    at Monitor.start (/data/node_modules/good/lib/monitor.js:105:19)
    at Object.exports.register (/data/node_modules/good/lib/index.js:42:20)
```